# what to say about low variability

Tags: variability

I did a survey and 4-point likert scale and most of  survey participants responded “Agree” or “Strongly Agree” 
and that made low variability in the summated scale scores,

what can I write for the reasons of low variability??

Comment: Low variability means that most participants agree on a score. What other explanation would you need and what for? It could be that your questions were flawed. A lot of surveys have flawed questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can write just what you already said: "Most people marked agree or strongly agree".

What *else* you should write depends on the purpose of the survey. For instance, if this was a survey of hotel guests and your questions were about general satisfaction, then a lot of "agree" and "strongly agree" is just what you want - it's a good thing.

On the other hand, if you are surveying attitudes about some controversial issue and you want a wider range of answers, then you will have to reword your questions next time to be "harder" - that is, less likely to get "agree" answers.